# C++ templates not known type at instantiation of template function

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++14

```
class BaseClass{
    public:
    std::string name;

    BaseClass(std::string typeName) : name(typeName) {};
    std::string GetType(){ return name; }
    };

template<typename T>
class DerivedClass : public BaseClass{
    public:
    T val;
    DerivedClass(std::string typeName, T arg) : BaseClass(typeName), val(arg) {};
    };

template<typename U, typename L>
void foo1(U & arg1, L & arg2)
{
    std::cout << arg1.val + arg2.val << std::endl;
}

void foo(BaseClass *arg1, BaseClass *arg2)
{
    if(arg1->GetType() == "Int")
    {
        auto p1 = (DerivedClass<int>*)arg1;
        if(arg2->GetType() == "Int")
        {
            auto p2 = (DerivedClass<int>*)arg2;
            foo1(*p1, *p2);
        }
        else if(arg2->GetType() == "Float")
        {
            auto p2 = (DerivedClass<float>*)arg2;
            foo1(*p1, *p2);
        }
        //else if () AND SO ON ........
    }
    else if(arg1->GetType() == "Float")
    {
        auto p1 = (DerivedClass<float>*)arg1;
        if(arg2->GetType() == "Int")
        {
            auto p2 = (DerivedClass<int>*)arg2;
            foo1(*p1, *p2);
        }
        else if(arg2->GetType() == "Float")
        {
            auto p2 = (DerivedClass<float>*)arg2;
            foo1(*p1, *p2);
        }
    }
    //else if () AND SO ON .....
}

int main()
{
   BaseClass *k1 = new DerivedClass<int>("Int", 2);
   BaseClass *k2 = new DerivedClass<float>("Float", 4.32);

   foo(k1, k2);

   return 0;
}
```

I have some similar problem as in test case above.
In function foo, is there any more elegant way of parsing multiple types to ladder of ifs to run template function?
Ladder of if for 1 or 2 arguments is not that bad, but it goes (arguments count)^(types count);

Answer (score 1):

You can use some *template magic* to generate the `if`...`else` chains for you. Firstly, write a generic *compile-time iteration* function:

```
template <typename TF, typename... Ts>
void for_each_arg(TF&& f, Ts&&... xs)
{
    return (void)(int[]){(f(std::forward<Ts>(xs)), 0)...};
}
```

You will also need something that binds a type to a string:

```
template <typename T>
struct bound_type 
{ 
    using type = T; 
    std::string _name;

    bound_type(std::string name) : _name{std::move(name)} { }
};
```

Then you can use it to check the types that you're interested in:

```
void foo(BaseClass *arg1, BaseClass *arg2)
{
    const auto for_bound_types = [](auto&& f)
    { 
        return for_each_arg(std::forward<decltype(f)>(f), 
                            bound_type<int>{"Int"},
                            bound_type<float>{"Float"},
                            bound_type<double>{"Double"});
    };

    for_bound_types([&](const auto& t1)
    {
        if(arg1->GetType() != t1._name) return;

        for_bound_types([&](const auto& t2)
        {
            if(arg2->GetType() != t2._name) return;

            using t1_type = typename std::decay_t<decltype(t1)>::type;
            using t2_type = typename std::decay_t<decltype(t2)>::type;

            auto& p1 = static_cast<DerivedClass<t1_type>&>(*arg1);
            auto& p2 = static_cast<DerivedClass<t2_type>&>(*arg2);
            foo1(p1, p2);
        }); 
    }); 
}
```

[**live wandbox example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/B8dqyLvWj91qcz61)

---

I would like to avoid using `std::string` here, but *compile-time strings* are unreasonably hard in C++. Something like [**typestring**](https://github.com/irrequietus/typestring) could be used instead.

---

In C++17, `for_each_arg` would be redundant thanks to *fold expressions*. `std::apply` could also be used to implement `for_bound_types`.

```
const auto for_bound_types = [](auto&& f)
{ 
    return std::apply([&](auto... xs){ (f(xs), ...); }, 
        std::make_tuple(bound_type<int>{"Int"},
                        bound_type<float>{"Float"},
                        bound_type<double>{"Double"}));
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The code generated will be `args^types`, but you can get the compiler to do it for you.

Get ahold of `std::variant` or `boost::variant` or write it yourself.

Have each argument give you either a `variant` with a copy, or a `variant` with a pointer-to the element or itself.

Use `std::visit` or `boost::apply_visitor` on these variants.

```
template<typename T>
class DerivedClass;

class BaseClass{
public:
  std::string name;
  virtual std::variant< DerivedClass<int>*, DerivedClass<double>* >
  self() = 0;

  BaseClass(std::string typeName) : name(typeName) {};
  std::string GetType(){ return name; }
};

template<typename T>
class DerivedClass : public BaseClass{
public:
  T val;
  DerivedClass(std::string typeName, T arg) : BaseClass(typeName), val(arg) {};
  std::variant< DerivedClass<int>*, DerivedClass<double>* >
  self() overload { return this; }
  std::variant< DerivedClass<int> const*, DerivedClass<double> const* >
  self() const overload { return this; }
};
```

Now we get:

```
void foo(BaseClass *arg1, BaseClass *arg2)
{
  auto a1 = arg1->self();
  auto a2 = arg2->self();
  auto foo_overloads = [](auto&&...args)->decltype(auto){ return foo(decltype(args)(args)...); };

  std::visit( foo_overloads, a1, a2 );
}
```

Now this punts the problem to "how do I write `std::visit` and `std::variant`".  But code for both is available on the internet.  And both are available as `std::experimental::variant` and `std::experimental::visit`.

Maintaining the list of types `int` `double` can be done in a type list, and the list `variant<DerivedClass<int>*, DerivedClass<double>*>` generated from it.

If you want the list to be bespoke and dynamic at runtime cost, you could instead take a type list, build a map from `std::string` to `std::function<variant< DerivedClass<Ts>*... >( BaseClass* )>` at the point of use (listing the types you support there), and do the same thing there.